# Test complains on 'await is reserved word'

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testing

I write test for my contract. By some reason compiler complains on `await` It is reserved word, but it used properly -- the rest of test functions works well.

```
await is a reserved word (42:2)
  40 |  it (`client buy good on the market - one good available on the market - no goods on the market`, function() {
  41 |      let goodSample = "Fruit";
> 42 |      await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSample), 10, {from: accounts[0], gas: 300000} );
     |      ^
  43 |      let good = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));
  44 |  
  45 |      let goodResult = await market.buy(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp$3.checkReservedWord (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4347:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4324:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3648:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1/ttruffle/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3306:19)

let market;

beforeEach(`create subject instance before each test`, async function() {
    market = await Market.new();
})

it(`client put good on the market - one good - one good is available on the market`, async function() {
    let goodSample = "Apple";
    await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSample), 10, {from: accounts[2], gas: 300000} );

    let good = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

    assert.equal(good[1], 10);
    assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(good[0]), goodSample);
})

it(`client put good on the market - two different goods - two goods are available on the market`, async function() {
    let goodFirstSample = "Fruit";
    let goodSecondSample = "Laptop";
    await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodFirstSample), 10, {from: accounts[1], gas: 300000} );
    await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSecondSample), 100, {from: accounts[1], gas: 300000} );

    let goodFirst = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodFirstSample));
    let goodSecond = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSecondSample));

    assert.equal(goodFirst[1], 10);
    assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(goodFirst[0]), goodFirstSample);
    assert.equal(goodSecond[1], 100);
    assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(goodSecond[0]), goodSecondSample);
})

it(`client put good on the market - two same goods - one good with two quantity is available on the market`, function() {

})

it (`client buy good on the market - one good available on the market - no goods on the market`, function() {
    let goodSample = "Fruit";
    await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSample), 10, {from: accounts[0], gas: 300000} );
    let good = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

    let goodResult = await market.buy(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

    assert.equal(good[0], accounts[0]);
    assert.equal(good[1], goodSample);
    assert.equal(good[2], 10);
})
```

Any clue why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last two `it` statements are missing the `async` keyword.

```
it(`client put good on the market - two same goods - one good with two quantity is available on the market`, function() { 
it (`client buy good on the market - one good available on the market - no goods on the market`, function() {
```

Should be:

```
it(`client put good on the market - two same goods - one good with two quantity is available on the market`, async function() { 
it (`client buy good on the market - one good available on the market - no goods on the market`, async function() {
```

Furthermore, I cleaned up the code using ESlint autofix

```
beforeEach(`create subject instance before each test`, async () => {
        market = await Market.new();
    });

    it(`client put good on the market - one good - one good is available on the market`, async () => {
        const goodSample = 'Apple';
        await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSample), 10, {from: accounts[2], gas: 300000});

        const good = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

        assert.equal(good[1], 10);
        assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(good[0]), goodSample);
    });

    it(`client put good on the market - two different goods - two goods are available on the market`, async () => {
        const goodFirstSample = 'Fruit';
        const goodSecondSample = 'Laptop';
        await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodFirstSample), 10, {from: accounts[1], gas: 300000});
        await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSecondSample), 100, {from: accounts[1], gas: 300000});

        const goodFirst = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodFirstSample));
        const goodSecond = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSecondSample));

        assert.equal(goodFirst[1], 10);
        assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(goodFirst[0]), goodFirstSample);
        assert.equal(goodSecond[1], 100);
        assert.equal(web3.toUtf8(goodSecond[0]), goodSecondSample);
    });

    it(`client put good on the market - two same goods - one good with two quantity is available on the market`, async () => {

    });

    it(`client buy good on the market - one good available on the market - no goods on the market`, async () => {
        const goodSample = 'Fruit';
        await market.sell(accounts[0], web3.fromAscii(goodSample), 10, {from: accounts[0], gas: 300000});
        const good = await market.getCostForGood(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

        const goodResult = await market.buy(web3.fromAscii(goodSample));

        assert.equal(good[0], accounts[0]);
        assert.equal(good[1], goodSample);
        assert.equal(good[2], 10);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! (RE: eslint) btw, at this moment I use mix of remix and notepad as my work environment. Do you have recommendation for better dev tools?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes! 

Visual Studio Code and the following plugins:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight

There are far more tools you'll find useful I'm sure, that's a good start though.